# Angular2 ionic2 when radio button checked then checkbox unchecked

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'm new angular2 developer, I have a question need help.

I have a list like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let folder of folders">
     <ion-checkbox checked="false" [(ngModel)]="folder.state"></ion-checkbox>
     <ion-radio radio-group [(ngModel)]="checkgroup" name="checkgroup" value="{{folder.id}}"></ion-radio>
```

And,I want to design UI, when the radio button checked then checkbox unchecked, when checkbox checked then radio button unchecked.

for example: if list have 4 checkbox and 2 radio button , when i use radio button then all checkbox state is unchecked . if i use checkbox then radio button state is unselected. I want to this effect.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: "For each div any one of them, between  checkbox and radio button, should be checked." - You want this behavior right?

Comment: example: if list have 4 checkbox and 2 radio button , when i selected radio button then all checkbox state is unchecked . if i use checkbox then radio button state is unselected.  I want to this effect